# Using regex to filter a list of strings but with wildcards (* and ?)?

Tags: c#, regex

I wonder if it is possible to modify a wildcard expression that uses `*` and `?` to transform it into a regular expression to verify if it matches some strings.

In other word, if I use filter (case insensitive): `*bl?e*` on those strings:

```
["Blue", "Black", "Red", "Light blue", "Light black"]
```

I want to get:

```
["Blue, "Light blue"].
```

Does anybody know how to do that with regular expression?
Is there a better way to do that other than using regular expression?

> Added to better clarify my thought...

Ok! ... as always, I thought I ask a super clear question and realize by the answers that I totally screw up my question. I would like to do a function that would filter a collection according to an expression (as a parameter to my function) that as same rules as dos ('*' '?'). I thought that using regex would be a nice idea. Am I right and what is the regex expression ? Also... I'm using C# and I wonder if I don not have access to anything that would do the job directly ?

I also look at (pretty good answer) [How do I specify a wildcard (for ANY character) in a c# regex statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034535/how-do-i-specify-a-wildcard-for-any-character-in-a-c-sharp-regex-statement)

I finally used Glob class in .net Patterns and Practices library.

But as reference this is my code to translate Glob exp to RegEx:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HQ.Util.General
{
    public class RegexUtil
    {
        public const string RegExMetaChars = @"*?(){}[]+-^$.|\"; // Do not change the order. Algo depends on it (2 first chars should be dos like wildcard char)

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert an filter expression with '*' (wildcard any char) and '?' (wildcard on char) into a valid regex and
        /// strip any special regex character
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dosLikeExpressionFilter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string DosLikeExpressionFilterToRegExFilterExpression(string dosLikeExpressionFilter)
        {
            StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
            regex.Append("(?i)"); // Case insensitive

            int startIndex = 0;
            int count = dosLikeExpressionFilter.Length;
            while (startIndex < count)
            {
                int metaIndex = RegExMetaChars.IndexOf(dosLikeExpressionFilter[startIndex]);
                if (metaIndex >= 0)
                {
                    if (metaIndex == 0)
                    {
                        regex.Append(".*");
                    }
                    else if (metaIndex == 1)
                    {
                        regex.Append(".");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        regex.Append("\\");
                        regex.Append(dosLikeExpressionFilter[startIndex]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    regex.Append(dosLikeExpressionFilter[startIndex]);
                }
                startIndex++;
            }

            return regex.ToString();
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// See 'DosLikeExpressionFilterToRegExFilterExpression' description to see what type of Regex is returned
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dosLikeExpressionFilter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Regex DosLikeExpressionFilterToRegEx(string dosLikeExpressionFilter)
        {
            return new Regex(DosLikeExpressionFilterToRegExFilterExpression(dosLikeExpressionFilter));
        }

        // ******************************************************************
    }
}
```

Comment: The type of pattern matching with `*` and `?` is called [`glob` (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). The language you are using might already provide method for applying this.

Comment: In which environment? Not really in DOS? You're, btw., confusing DOS with cmd.exe/command.com and other Shells with the same syntax. DOS was an operating system.

Comment: Thanks a lot to Felix ! It's your comment which set me on the best solution ! ==>  .net Glob class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
               Any single character    Any number of characters   Character range
Glob syntax            ?                           *                    [0-9]
Regex syntax           .                           .*                   [0-9]
```

So `Bl?e` (glob) becomes `Bl.e` (regex), and `*Bl?e*` becomes `.*Bl.e.*`.

As Joey correctly noted, you can (usually, depending on the regex engine) prepend `(?i)` to your regex to make it case-insensitive.

Be aware, though, that lots of characters that have no special meaning in globbing patterns do have special meaning in regex, so you can't just do a simple search-and-replace from glob to regex.

Comment: Is `*` greedy in glob (I don't know)?

Comment: @FelixKling: Does it matter? Since `*` is the only variable-length pattern there is, I can't think of a situation where greedy vs. lazy would matter.

Comment: using the special char "." will make your regex match any character what I'm guessing you don't want ( "bl(e" would be matched for ex). Use \w instead.

Comment: I don't know, I have not given it much thought... I just wanted to mention it so that it is not overlooked and the actual regex equivalent would be `.*?`. If you say it does not matter, it's fine for me.

Comment: @lcfseth: That's not the point of the question. Eric wants to know what `?` (glob) means in regex. Not what `[A-Za-z]` (glob) means in regex.

Comment: Ok! ... as always, I thought I ask a super clear question and realize by the answers that I totally screw up my question.
I would like to do a function that would filter a collection according to an expression that as same rules as dos ('*' '?').
I thought that using regex would be a nice idea. Am I right and what is the regex expression ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer seems very good but not as perfect as I would like. But I will probably check it as the right answer. The reason I say that: it's either imcomplete because it miss what I should take care of (all special character) but it sounds like it could be a bad idea to use regex for that... too many special characters to take care of into the substitution. But I will wait to find a real solution to my prob before marking any answer.

Comment: Thanks, it was pretty close. I also used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034535/how-do-i-specify-a-wildcard-for-any-character-in-a-c-sharp-regex-statement as resource. But honestly, it was Felix Kling remark that light me on the solution I finally choose. I did program the code to translate the glob expression to regex but realized after, that it exists in .net a class "Glob" that does exactly what I wanted. thanks to all of you, it was a real pleasure to read you and very very instructive !!!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to solve the same problem (use * and ? wildcard patterns from user input to filter a list of arbitrary strings) but with the extension to possibly escape stars or question marks to be searched for also.

Since the SQL LIKE operator (where those wildcards are % and _) usually offers the backslash for escape I took the same approach. That complicates the usually simple strategy to use Regex.Escape() and replacing * with .* and ? with . for using a Regex (see many other answers to the problem).

A method providing a Regex for some wildcard pattern is sketched in following code. It is implemented as an extension method for C# string. Doc tags and comments should explain the code completely:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Interpret this string as wildcard pattern and create a corresponding regular expression. 
    /// Rules for simple wildcard matching are:
    /// * Matches any character zero or more times.
    /// ? Matches any character exactly one time.
    /// \ Backslash can be used to escape above wildcards (and itself) for an explicit match,
    /// e.g. \* would then match a single star, \? matches a question mark and \\ matches a backslash.
    /// If \ is not followed by star, question mark or backslash it also matches a single backslash.
    /// Character set matching (by use of rectangular braces []) is NOT used and regarded in this implementation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wildPat">This string to be used as wildcard match pattern.</param>
    /// <param name="caseSens">Optional parameter for case sensitive matching - default is case insensitive.</param>
    /// <returns>New instance of a regular expression performing the requested matches.
    /// If input string is null or empty, null is returned.</returns>
    public static Regex CreateWildcardRegEx(this string wildPat, bool caseSens = false)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wildPat))
           return null;

        // 1. STEP: Escape all special characters used in Regex later to avoid unwanted behavior.
        // Regex.Escape() prepends a backslash to any of following characters: \*+?|{[()^$.# and white space 
        wildPat = Regex.Escape(wildPat);

        // 2. STEP: Replace all three possible occuring escape sequences defined for our 
        // wildcard pattern with temporary sub strings that CANNOT exist after 1. STEP anymore.
        // Prepare some constant strings used below - @ in C# makes literal strings really literal - a backslash needs not be repeated!
        const string esc    = @"\\";    // Matches a backslash in a Regex
        const string any    = @"\*";    // Matches a star in a Regex
        const string sgl    = @"\?";    // Matches a question mark in a Regex
        const string tmpEsc = @"||\";   // Instead of doubled | any character Regex.Escape() escapes would do (except \ itself!)
        const string tmpAny =  "||*";   // See comment above
        const string tmpSgl =  "||?";   // See comment above

        // Watch that string.Replace() in C# will NOT stop replacing after the first match but continues instead...
        wildPat = wildPat.Replace(Regex.Escape(esc), tmpEsc)
                         .Replace(Regex.Escape(any), tmpAny)
                         .Replace(Regex.Escape(sgl), tmpSgl);

        // 3. STEP: Substitute our (in 1. STEP escaped) simple wildcards with the Regex counterparts.
        const string regAny = ".*";             // Matches any character zero or more times in a Regex
        wildPat = wildPat.Replace(any, regAny)
                         .Replace(sgl, ".");    // . matches any character in a Regex

        // 4. STEP: Revert the temporary replacements of 2. STEP (in reverse order) and replace with what a Regex really needs to match
        wildPat = wildPat.Replace(tmpSgl, sgl)
                         .Replace(tmpAny, any)
                         .Replace(tmpEsc, esc);

        // 5. STEP: (Optional, for performance) - Simplify multiply occuring * wildcards (cases of ******* or similar)
        // Replace with the regAny string - Use a single Regex.Replace() instead of string.Contains() with string.Replace() in a while loop 
        wildPat = Regex.Replace(wildPat, @"(\.\*){2,}", regAny);

        // 6. STEP: Finalize the Regex with begin and end line tags
        return new Regex('^' + wildPat + '$', caseSens ? RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // 2. and 4. STEP would be obsolete if we don't wanted to have the ability to escape * and ? characters for search
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
^([\w,\s]*bl\we[\w,\s]*)
```

It basically recognize any set of word and spaces which contains a word starting with "bl" and ending with "e" with one character in between.
Or

```
^([\w,\s]*bl(\w+)e[\w,\s]*)
```

if you want to recognize any word starting with "bl" and ending with "e".

The other alternative is to use some inexact matching algorithms over strings. Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for though.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question. They aren't specifically trying to solve the "search for blue" problem, they are asking what the regexp equivalent to * and ? are.

Comment: Ok! ... as always, I thought I ask a super clear question and realize by the answers that I totally screw up my question. I would like to do a function that would filter a collection according to an expression that as same rules as dos ('*' '?'). I thought that using regex would be a nice idea. Am I right and what is the regex expression ?

Comment: Regex offer the same possibilities as dos and much more, so I would say it is a nice idea. Now the question is how to convert dos expression to RegEx, and the answer was given I think.

Comment: Thanks lcfseth for the expression. I appreciate it. Like you said, Tim was very close to what I was looking for. Somebody gave you -1 but I think it was a little hard on you. I will try to put you back to 0 instead of -1... :-) ... I really appreciate the effort and the try to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Just as reference... I actually use that code:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HQ.Util.General
{
    /*
        Usage:

           _glob = new FilterGlob(filterExpression, _caseSensitive);            


            public bool IsMatch(string s)
            {
                return _glob.IsMatch(s);
            }
    */


    /// <summary>
    /// Glob stand for: Pattern matching. Supported character are "?" and "*".
    /// </summary>
    public class FilterGlob
    {
        private readonly Regex pattern;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new <see cref="T:Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Glob"/> instance that matches the given pattern.
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pattern">The pattern to use. See <see cref="T:Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Glob"/> summary for
        ///             details of the patterns supported.</param><param name="caseSensitive">If true, perform a case sensitive match.
        ///             If false, perform a case insensitive comparison.</param>
        public FilterGlob(string pattern, bool caseSensitive = true)
        {
            this.pattern = FilterGlob.GlobPatternToRegex(pattern, caseSensitive);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks to see if the given string matches the pattern.
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">String to check.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// True if it matches, false if it doesn't.
        /// </returns>
        public bool IsMatch(string s)
        {
            return this.pattern.IsMatch(s);
        }

        private static Regex GlobPatternToRegex(string pattern, bool caseSensitive)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(pattern);
            string[] strArray = new string[9]
            {
                "\\",
                ".",
                "$",
                "^",
                "{",
                "(",
                "|",
                ")",
                "+"
            };

            foreach (string oldValue in strArray)
            {
                stringBuilder.Replace(oldValue, "\\" + oldValue);
            }

            stringBuilder.Replace("*", ".*");
            stringBuilder.Replace("?", ".");
            stringBuilder.Insert(0, "^");
            stringBuilder.Append("$");

            RegexOptions options = caseSensitive ? RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

            return new Regex(((object)stringBuilder).ToString(), options);
        }

    }
}
```