# Regex matching all but not empty

Tags: regex

A line has to be validated through regex,

1. line can contain any characters, spaces, digits, floats.
2. line should not be blank

I tried this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9~`!#$%^&*()_+-]+ //thinking of all the characters
```

Any alternative solution will be helpful

Comment: So you're saying that absolutely anything is allowed, as long as the line isn't empty? Why do you even want to use a regex for this, as opposed to the `length` function that I'm sure your language has?

Comment: do you need regex for this? why not just trim the line and check if it is not an empty string?

Comment: For `2. line should not be blank` -- should a line containing only whitespace be counted as "blank" or not? It makes a difference to the regex or to non-regex methods.

Comment: I believe this answer will help you.  
Good luck!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085539/regular-expression-for-anything-but-an-empty-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 33):

Try this to match a line that contains more than just whitespace

```
/.*\S.*/
```

This means

`/` = delimiter
`.*` = zero or more of anything but newline
`\S` = anything except a whitespace (newline, tab, space)

so you get
match anything but newline + something not whitespace + anything but newline

if whitespace only line counts as not whitespace, then replace the rule with `/.+/`, which will match 1 or more of anything.

Comment: Still works in 2023! I used this variation for search and replace in **Notepad++**:  Find: `(.*) \S`, REPLACE WITH: `- \1`. This adds a dash and space in front of every non blank line essentially converting the items to a bullet list for **markdown** like in SO

Answer (score 18):

try:

```
.+
```

The . matches any character, and the plus requires least one.

Comment: -1, sorry. In most regex engines, `[.]` will only match an actual period. You mean `.`.

Answer (score 7):

Try : `[^()]`

In python with `re.match()` :

```
  >>> re.match( r"[^()]", '' )
  >>> re.match( r"[^()]", ' ' )
  <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100486168>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just check if the line matches `^$` if it does then it's blank and you can use that as a failure, otherwise it will pass.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^.+$
```

I used this in python BeautifulSoup when trying to find tags which do not have an attribute that is empty. It worked well. Example is below:

```
# get first 'a' tag in the html content where 'href' attribute is not empty
parsed_content.find("a", {"href":re.compile("^.+$")})
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
^[A-Za-z0-9,-_.\s]+$
```

this string will return true for alphabets, numbers and `,-_.` but will not accept an empty string.

`+` -> Quantifier, Matches between 1 and unlimited.

`*` -> Quantifier, Matches between 0 and unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

This one will match everything but NOT BLANK string:

```
^(\s|\S)*(\S)+(\s|\S)*$
```

Blank string is those containing empty characters only (tabs, spaces etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This one will match every line with at least 1 character:

```
(.*?(\n))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\S+[^ ]$
```

`^` - beginning of line

`\S`   - any non-whitespace character

`+` - one or more occurence

`[^ ]` - character not in the set (in this case only space), there is a space between ^ and ] this will match dsadasd^adsadas

`$` - end of line

[image: Something to help you]

Comment: Why is `[^ ]` needed? What does it match which `\S` does not?

Answer (score 0):

`.*` - matches between zero and unlimited times any character (except for line terminators)

`\S` - matches any non-whitespace character

Answer: `.*[\S].*`

`'aaaaa'` match

`'aaaaa '` match

`' aaaaa'` match

`' aaaaa '` match

`'aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa'` match

`' aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa'` match

`'aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa '` match

`' aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa '` match

`'     '` does not match

You can test this regular expression at: **https://regex101.com**