# Make regular expression not match empty string?

Tags: regex

I have regex which works fine in my application, but it matches an empty string too, i.e. no error occurs when the input is empty. How do I modify this regex so that it will not match an empty string ? Note that I DON'T want to change any other functionality of this regex.

This is the regex which I'm using: `^([0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]*)$`

I don't know a lot about regex formulation myself, which is why I'm asking. I have searched for an answer, but couldn't find a direct one. Closest I got to was this: [regular expression for anything but an empty string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085539/regular-expression-for-anything-but-an-empty-string-in-c-sharp), but that doesn't really work for me ..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace `*` with `+`, as `*` means "0 or more occurrences", while `+` means "at least one occurrence"

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of pattern types that can match empty strings. The OP regex belongs to an `^.*$` type, and it is easy to modify it to prevent empty string matching by replacing `*` (= `{0,}`) quantifier (meaning *zero or more*) with the `+` (= `{1,}`) quantifier (meaning *one or more*), as has already been mentioned in the posts here.

There are other pattern types matching empty strings, and it is not always obvious how to prevent *them* from matching empty strings.

Here are a few of those patterns with solutions:

> [`[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/RWmdAg/1) **⇒** [`(?:[^"\\]|\\.)+`](https://regex101.com/r/RWmdAg/2)
>
> `abc||def` **⇒** `abc|def` (remove the extra `|` alternation operator)
>
> [`^a*$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/1) **⇒** [`^a+$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/2) (`+` matches 1 or more chars)
>
> [`^(a)?(b)?(c)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/5) **⇒** [`^(?!$)(a)?(b)?(c?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/4) (the `(?!$)` negative lookahead fails the match if end of string is at the start of the string)
>   
>               or         **⇒** [`^(?=.)(a)?(b)?(c?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/4) (the `(?=.)` positive lookahead requires at least a single char, `.` may match or not line break chars depending on modifiers/regex flavor)
>
> [`^$|^abc$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/6) **⇒** [`^abc$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/7) (remove the `^$` alternative that enables a regex to match an empty string)
>
> [`^(?:abc|def)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/8) **⇒** [`^(?:abc|def)$`](https://regex101.com/r/RFuZE7/9) (remove the `?` quantifier that made the `(?:abc|def)` group optional)

To make `\b(?:north|south)?(?:east|west)?\b` (that [matches](https://regex101.com/r/CjNomx/1) `north`, `south`, `east`, `west`, `northeast`, `northwest`, `southeast`, `southwest`), the word boundaries [must be precised](https://regex101.com/r/mZqzVX/1): make the initial word boundary only match start of words by adding `(?<!\w)` after it, and let the trailing word boundary only match at the end of words by adding `(?!\w)` after it.

> `\b(?:north|south)?(?:east|west)?\b` **⇒** `\b(?<!\w)(?:north|south)?(?:east|west)?\b(?!\w)`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `+` or the `{min, max}` Syntax:

```
^[0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]{1,}$
```

or

```
^[0-9\(\)\/\+ \-]+$
```

By the way: this is a great source for learning regular expressions (and it's fun): http://regexone.com/

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need to replace Replace `*` with `+`, as `+` matches 1 or more character. However inside character class you don't to do all that escaping you're doing. Your regex can be simplified to:

```
^([0-9()\/+ -]+)$
```