# Trying to matchAll a regex on a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to `string.matchAll` the following string:

`const text = 'textA [aaa](bbb) textB [ccc](ddd) textC'`

I want to match the following:

- 1st: `"textA [aaa](bbb)"`
- 2nd: `" textB [ccc](ddd)"`
- 3rd: `" textC"`

**NOTE:** The capturing groups are already present in the `regex`. That's what I need.

It's almost working, but so far I couldn't think of a way to match the last part of the string, which is just `" textC"`, and doesn't have the `[*](*)` pattern.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const text = 'textA [aaa](bbb) textB [ccc](ddd) textC'
const regexp = /(.*?)\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)/g;

const array = Array.from(text.matchAll(regexp));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array[0][0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array[1][0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array[2][0]));
```

**UPDATE:**

Besides the good solutions provided in the answers below, this is also an option:

```js
const text= 'textA [aaa](bbb) textB [ccc](ddd) textC'

const regexp = /(?!$)([^[]*)(?:\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\))?/gm;

const array = Array.from(text.matchAll(regexp));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: try this : (\w+)\s*(?:\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\))?

Comment: Anything wrong with `(.+\)) (.+\)) (.+)`?

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56637630/3832970) will work to split any string with any pattern while keeping the matched text in the left-hand split chunk. Is it working for you? Are you sure the result you need is the one you showed in the question? Is `textC` a placeholder and it can just be equal to `word 1 word 2 and word 3 and so on....` and you need to get this text as a single item in the resulting array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I've ended up using:

```js
const text= 'textA [aaa](bbb) textB [ccc](ddd) textC'

const regexp = /(?!$)([^[]*)(?:\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\))?/gm;

const array = Array.from(text.matchAll(regexp));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because there is no third match. After the first two matches, the only thing left in the string is "text C":

https://regex101.com/r/H9Kn0G/1/

to fix this, make the whole second part optional (also note the initial `\w` instead of `.` to prevent that dot from eating the whole string, as well as the "grouping only" parens used to surround the optional part, which keeps your match groups the same):

`(\w+)(?:\s\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\))?`

https://regex101.com/r/Smo1y1/2/

Comment: The word character is too restrictive for me. I want to match ANY string followed by the pattern `[+](+)`, and if multiple patterns `[+](+)` are written together one after the other I want to match them 1 by 1.

Comment: to match literally anything up to that next bracket, try this: `((?:(?!\[).)+)(?:\s?\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\))?`. https://regex101.com/r/HqbTpU/1/  I added a 'tempered token' with that negative lookahead, more complex obviously.

Comment: @ScottWeaver Please never use a tempered greedy token when you restrict a `.` with  a single char. `(?:(?!\[).)+` (almost) = `[^[]+`. It is equal to something like `[^[\n\r]+` in fact. The negated character class works much faster.

Comment: yes, that's a little simpler and works the same. https://regex101.com/r/vMFKXH/1/

Comment: Besides, [your regex solution is easy to break](https://regex101.com/r/HqbTpU/3) if there are "standalone" brackets before `[...](...)` construction.

Comment: every regex solution is easy to break. the robustness required is up to OP - sometimes regex is better, sometimes algorithmic approaches are needed.

Comment: The exact solution that I need is `([^[]*)(?:\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\))?` , but it matches the last position as a zero-length. If I change it to `([^[]+)(?:\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\))?` requiring the first group to have at least 1 char, I get rid of the last position match, but I can't match multiple patterns of the second group when they're together like `[+](+)[+](+)[+](+)...` Any easy way to get rid of that last position zero-length?

Comment: I think I found what I need: `(?!$)([^[]*)(?:\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\))?`

Comment: multiple [+](+)...N is a different ballgame though, right? because then it's an arbitrary length, which cannot be captured into match groups correctly.  (you can capture the whole sequence then do another parse)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1: Splitting through matching

You may split by matching the pattern and getting substrings from the previous index up to the end of the match:

```js
const text = 'textA [aaa](bbb) textB [ccc](ddd) textC'
const regexp = /\[[^\][]*\]\([^()]*\)/g;
let m, idx = 0, result=[];
while(m=regexp.exec(text)) {
  result.push(text.substring(idx, m.index + m[0].length).trim());
  idx = m.index + m[0].length;
}
if (idx < text.length) {
  result.push(text.substring(idx, text.length).trim())
}
console.log(result);
```

Note:

- `\[[^\][]*\]\([^()]*\)` matches `[`, any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` (with `[^\][]*`), then `](`, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` (with `[^()]*`) and then a `)` (see the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ouOhvr/1))
- The capturing groups are removed, but you may restore them and save in the resulting array separately (or in another array) if needed
- `.trim()` is added to get rid of the leading/trailing whitespace (remove if not necessary).

## Solution 2: Matching optional pattern

The idea is to match any chars before the pattern you have and then match either your pattern or end of string:

```
let result = text.match(/(?!$)(.*?)(?:\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)|$)/g);
```

If the string can have line breaks, replace `.` with `[\s\S]`, or consider this pattern:

```
let result = text.match(/(?!$)([\s\S]*?)(?:\[([^\][]*)\]\(([^()]*)\)|$)/g);
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouOhvr/2).

JS demo:

```js
const text = 'textA [aaa](bbb) textB [ccc](ddd) textC'
const regexp = /(?!$)(.*?)(?:\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)|$)/g;

const array = Array.from(text.matchAll(regexp));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array[0][0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array[1][0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array[2][0]));
```

**Regex details**

- `(?!$)` - not at the end of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (change to `[\s\S]*?` if there can be line breaks or add `s` modifier since you target ECMAScript 2018)
- `(?:\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)|$)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)` - `[`, Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible, `](`, Group 3: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and a `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: Sorry I took too long to give a feedback. Your answer seems too work (it's missing some spaces from `textB` and `textC`), but my main problem with it is that it seemed not so readable to me. I would like it better to work with a `regex` and the `matchAll` method. Thank you.

Comment: I've got this `regex` which is basically working, but it's matching a zero-length match on the last position. `/([^\[]*)?(?:\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\))?/gm`

Comment: @cbdev420 So, you want to use an unreadable regex solution? :) `/(?=[\s\S])([\s\S]*?)(?:\[([^\][]*)\]\(([^()]*)\)|$)/g`

Comment: I think that the regex I got now which is almost working is pretty readable. `([^\[]*)?(?:\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\))?` Basically a group to match any character but the left bracket `[` if possible, then I try to match the pattern `[+](+)`. But I agree that readability is a point of view. It's really personal.

Comment: Can't I modify my current regex to ger rid of the last match? Or would I need to go to a completely different path? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @cbdev420 I added the fixed regex solution to the answer. With two variations

Comment: Thanks! I'm still testing some options but yours is working for sure.

Comment: @cbdev420 `(?=.)` or `(?!$)` are synonymic. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50188154/3832970).