# How to avoid empty strings in pythong's regular expression function re.findAll?

Tags: python, python-re

I use python's re module to recognize integers in a sentence. It produces empty strings as well. Any idea on how to remove those empty strings?

```
In [15]: myre="[0-9]*"

In [16]: re.findall(myre,"23")
Out[16]: ['23', '']

In [17]: re.findall(myre,"23 is a good number.")
Out[17]:
['23',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '']
```

Comment: This should answer your question: [Make regular expression not match empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620735/make-regular-expression-not-match-empty-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your regex matches 0 or more occurences of digits. Change it to `[0-9]+`  or `\d+` and try out.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `[0-9]+` rather than `[0-9]*`; the latter matches against 0 or more (meaning that the digits are optional); `+`, however, matches against one or more.