# Regular Expression Not working in C# Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm using this regular expression

```
^(?=.{0,150}$)\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

for validating Email Addresses. when I Enter this Email Address : `konstinköpet@gmail.com` . It is working using Regular expression validator(it is showing InValidEmail Address), but when validating in C# code it is not working(taking it as validEmail Address)

```
return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(
    strEmailAddress,
    @"^(?=.{0,150}$)\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem you want the address: konstinköpet@gmail.com to fail validation because it contains Unicode characters. Your regex uses the \w character class which by default matches any word characters, this includes any Unicode characters defined as letters.

You can force \w to be just [a-zA-Z_0-9] by specifying RegexOptions.ECMAScript you code becomes:

```
return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(
    strEmailAddress,
    @"^(?=.{0,150}$)\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.RegexOptions.ECMAScript
);
```

Alternatively you could replace the \w with [a-zA-Z_0-9] which would have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you , Its Working !! I have used two regular expressions to solve this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one:

```
Regex.IsMatch(strEmailAddress, @"^[\\p{L}0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[\\p{L}0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[\\p{L}0-9](?:[\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\p{L}0-9])?\.)+[\\p{L}0-9](?:[\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\p{L}0-9])?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

it will admit non ASCII character

Comment: It should not admit Non-Ascii Character, I need a regular expression for not accepting Non-Ascii characters ,Special Characters and SPaces

Comment: You have to add this condition: [^\x00-\x7F].

Comment: @user3270152 `ö` is not ASCII. Maybe I misunderstood the problem. In any case, in .NET/C#, [\w includes non-ASCII Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998519/net-regex-what-is-the-word-character-w)

Answer (score 0):

End you Regex with `$` as an example see this.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be using the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress class to validate the email address.

Try using the following code:

```
try {
    MailAddress addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
    return true;
}
catch {
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Regex solution:

```
bool d = Regex.IsMatch("konstinköpet@gmail.com", @"^([\p{L}\.\-\d]+)@([\p{L}\-\.\d]+)((\.(\p{L}){2,63})+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Works for me.

Comment: I tried  this one aswell , it is not working... it should not admit Non-Ascii Character

Comment: Using a Try/Catch isn't the best way to make a test. You need to test is something accord to a condition, not try to do something and look if it failed or not.

Comment: @Eliran , I tried this , it is not working ... it is returning true