# Using regex to match international/unicode alphanumeric characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I'm trying to use Javascript's string.match() function for a fairly simple task: extract all the words from a string and then count the number of occurrences of each word. The regular expression:

```
/\w+/g
```

works fine for this task except for the fact that it can't handle any sort of unicode/international characters. What's the best/cleanest way to be able to match accented characters, the Cyrillic alphabet, and any other major alphabets?

If it happens to matter, I'm currently coding in a Node.js environment.

Comment: Try http://xregexp.com/

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping there was some sort of built-in way, but this library looks pretty nice. Thanks!

Comment: What is a "major alphabet"? An alphabet used by white people, rich countries or perhaps countries that have the atomic weapon?

Comment: Perhaps I should have phrased it as "any alphabet included in Unicode."

Comment: Except for languages which don't share their alphabets with others, there is generally no tool/library to match only alphabet of a specific language. You won't find French, or German, or Spanish alphabet predefined character classes. (Well, if there is one, I'd also want to take a look at it).

Comment: Yeah, I just said "most languages" because I wasn't sure if some alphabets might be easier to support than others.

Answer (score 10):

**[XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)**:

In comments, [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs), suggested [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/). If you use it, you will need the [Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode), and [Categories 1.2.0](http://xregexp.com/addons/unicode/unicode-categories.js) for it. This package and plugins appear to be a robust, and significant addition to regular expressions in JavaScript. You will then need to make sure to construct your regex using multiple character classes because it does not define a `\w` equivalent.  Be sure to also include at least the "Mn" class of non-spacing marks as those are commonly used to construct non-English characters.

**Stand alone definitions of Unicode character types:**

Prior to knowing about [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/), I adapted a version of Unicode from the net to use in a project. Below is an implementation of Unicode character classes. It is significantly less capable than the full XRegExp add-in, but would get the job done for the simple regex which you mention.

You would want: `myRegex = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.w + "]+", "g");`

```
/* From:
    http://difnet.com.br/opensource/unicode_hack.js
    It has been significantly modified.
    Modifications are copyright 2014 Makyen and released under the MPL 2.0.
        This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
        License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
        file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
*/
/*! unicode_hack.js
    Copyright (C) 2010-2012  Marcelo Gibson de Castro Gonçalves. All rights reserved.

    Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
    are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
    notice and this notice are preserved.  This file is offered as-is,
    without any warranty.
*/
Unicode = {
    /* Strings to match Unicode characters in the BMP according to their Unicode category.
       Extracted from Unicode specification, version 5.0.0, source:
       http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/
    */
    /*
        Abbr    Long                Description
        Lu  Uppercase_Letter        an uppercase letter
        Ll  Lowercase_Letter        a lowercase letter
        Lt  Titlecase_Letter        a digraphic character, with first part uppercase
        LC  Cased_Letter            Lu | Ll | Lt
        Lm  Modifier_Letter         a modifier letter
        Lo  Other_Letter            other letters, including syllables and ideographs
        L   Letter                  Lu | Ll | Lt | Lm | Lo
        Mn  Nonspacing_Mark         a nonspacing combining mark (zero advance width)
        Mc  Spacing_Mark            a spacing combining mark (positive advance width)
        Me  Enclosing_Mark          an enclosing combining mark
        M   Mark                    Mn | Mc | Me
        Nd  Decimal_Number          a decimal digit
        Nl  Letter_Number           a letterlike numeric character
        No  Other_Number            a numeric character of other type
        N   Number                  Nd | Nl | No
        Pc  Connector_Punctuation   a connecting punctuation mark, like a tie
        Pd  Dash_Punctuation        a dash or hyphen punctuation mark
        Ps  Open_Punctuation        an opening punctuation mark (of a pair)
        Pe  Close_Punctuation       a closing punctuation mark (of a pair)
        Pi  Initial_Punctuation     an initial quotation mark
        Pf  Final_Punctuation       a final quotation mark
        Po  Other_Punctuation       a punctuation mark of other type
        P   Punctuation             Pc | Pd | Ps | Pe | Pi | Pf | Po
        Sm  Math_Symbol             a symbol of mathematical use
        Sc  Currency_Symbol         a currency sign
        Sk  Modifier_Symbol         a non-letterlike modifier symbol
        So  Other_Symbol            a symbol of other type
        S   Symbol                  Sm | Sc | Sk | So
        Zs  Space_Separator         a space character (of various non-zero widths)
        Zl  Line_Separator          U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR only
        Zp  Paragraph_Separator     U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR only
        Z   Separator               Zs | Zl | Zp
        Cc  Control                 a C0 or C1 control code
        Cf  Format                  a format control character
        Cs  Surrogate               a surrogate code point
        Co  Private_Use             a private-use character
        Cn  Unassigned              a reserved unassigned code point or a noncharacter
        C   Other                   Cc | Cf | Cs | Co | Cn
    */
    /* Alpha Sorted
        Abbr    Long                Description
        C   Other                   Cc | Cf | Cs | Co | Cn
        Cc  Control                 a C0 or C1 control code
        Cf  Format                  a format control character
        Cn  Unassigned              a reserved unassigned code point or a noncharacter
        Co  Private_Use             a private-use character
        Cs  Surrogate               a surrogate code point
        L   Letter                  Lu | Ll | Lt | Lm | Lo
        LC  Cased_Letter            Lu | Ll | Lt
        Ll  Lowercase_Letter        a lowercase letter
        Lm  Modifier_Letter         a modifier letter
        Lo  Other_Letter            other letters, including syllables and ideographs
        Lt  Titlecase_Letter        a digraphic character, with first part uppercase
        Lu  Uppercase_Letter        an uppercase letter
        M   Mark                    Mn | Mc | Me
        Mc  Spacing_Mark            a spacing combining mark (positive advance width)
        Me  Enclosing_Mark          an enclosing combining mark
        Mn  Nonspacing_Mark         a nonspacing combining mark (zero advance width)
        N   Number                  Nd | Nl | No
        Nd  Decimal_Number          a decimal digit
        Nl  Letter_Number           a letterlike numeric character
        No  Other_Number            a numeric character of other type
        P   Punctuation             Pc | Pd | Ps | Pe | Pi | Pf | Po
        Pc  Connector_Punctuation   a connecting punctuation mark, like a tie
        Pd  Dash_Punctuation        a dash or hyphen punctuation mark
        Pe  Close_Punctuation       a closing punctuation mark (of a pair)
        Pf  Final_Punctuation       a final quotation mark
        Pi  Initial_Punctuation     an initial quotation mark
        Po  Other_Punctuation       a punctuation mark of other type
        Ps  Open_Punctuation        an opening punctuation mark (of a pair)
        S   Symbol                  Sm | Sc | Sk | So
        Sc  Currency_Symbol         a currency sign
        Sk  Modifier_Symbol         a non-letterlike modifier symbol
        Sm  Math_Symbol             a symbol of mathematical use
        So  Other_Symbol            a symbol of other type
        Z   Separator               Zs | Zl | Zp
        Zl  Line_Separator          U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR only
        Zp  Paragraph_Separator     U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR only
        Zs  Space_Separator         a space character (of various non-zero widths)
    */

    Cc:'\u0000-\u001f\u007f-\u009f',
    Cf:'\u00ad\u0600-\u0603\u06dd\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200b-\u200f\u202a-\u202e\u2060-\u2063\u206a-\u206f\ufeff\ufff9-\ufffb',
    Co:'\ue000-\uf8ff',
    Cs:'\ud800\udb7f\udb80\udbff\udc00\udfff',
    Ll:'\u0061-\u007a\u00aa\u00b5\u00ba\u00df-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0101\u0103\u0105\u0107\u0109\u010b\u010d\u010f\u0111\u0113\u0115\u0117\u0119\u011b\u011d\u011f\u0121\u0123\u0125\u0127\u0129\u012b\u012d\u012f\u0131\u0133\u0135\u0137\u0138\u013a\u013c\u013e\u0140\u0142\u0144\u0146\u0148\u0149\u014b\u014d\u014f\u0151\u0153\u0155\u0157\u0159\u015b\u015d\u015f\u0161\u0163\u0165\u0167\u0169\u016b\u016d\u016f\u0171\u0173\u0175\u0177\u017a\u017c\u017e-\u0180\u0183\u0185\u0188\u018c\u018d\u0192\u0195\u0199-\u019b\u019e\u01a1\u01a3\u01a5\u01a8\u01aa\u01ab\u01ad\u01b0\u01b4\u01b6\u01b9\u01ba\u01bd-\u01bf\u01c6\u01c9\u01cc\u01ce\u01d0\u01d2\u01d4\u01d6\u01d8\u01da\u01dc\u01dd\u01df\u01e1\u01e3\u01e5\u01e7\u01e9\u01eb\u01ed\u01ef\u01f0\u01f3\u01f5\u01f9\u01fb\u01fd\u01ff\u0201\u0203\u0205\u0207\u0209\u020b\u020d\u020f\u0211\u0213\u0215\u0217\u0219\u021b\u021d\u021f\u0221\u0223\u0225\u0227\u0229\u022b\u022d\u022f\u0231\u0233-\u0239\u023c\u023f\u0240\u0242\u0247\u0249\u024b\u024d\u024f-\u0293\u0295-\u02af\u037b-\u037d\u0390\u03ac-\u03ce\u03d0\u03d1\u03d5-\u03d7\u03d9\u03db\u03dd\u03df\u03e1\u03e3\u03e5\u03e7\u03e9\u03eb\u03ed\u03ef-\u03f3\u03f5\u03f8\u03fb\u03fc\u0430-\u045f\u0461\u0463\u0465\u0467\u0469\u046b\u046d\u046f\u0471\u0473\u0475\u0477\u0479\u047b\u047d\u047f\u0481\u048b\u048d\u048f\u0491\u0493\u0495\u0497\u0499\u049b\u049d\u049f\u04a1\u04a3\u04a5\u04a7\u04a9\u04ab\u04ad\u04af\u04b1\u04b3\u04b5\u04b7\u04b9\u04bb\u04bd\u04bf\u04c2\u04c4\u04c6\u04c8\u04ca\u04cc\u04ce\u04cf\u04d1\u04d3\u04d5\u04d7\u04d9\u04db\u04dd\u04df\u04e1\u04e3\u04e5\u04e7\u04e9\u04eb\u04ed\u04ef\u04f1\u04f3\u04f5\u04f7\u04f9\u04fb\u04fd\u04ff\u0501\u0503\u0505\u0507\u0509\u050b\u050d\u050f\u0511\u0513\u0561-\u0587\u1d00-\u1d2b\u1d62-\u1d77\u1d79-\u1d9a\u1e01\u1e03\u1e05\u1e07\u1e09\u1e0b\u1e0d\u1e0f\u1e11\u1e13\u1e15\u1e17\u1e19\u1e1b\u1e1d\u1e1f\u1e21\u1e23\u1e25\u1e27\u1e29\u1e2b\u1e2d\u1e2f\u1e31\u1e33\u1e35\u1e37\u1e39\u1e3b\u1e3d\u1e3f\u1e41\u1e43\u1e45\u1e47\u1e49\u1e4b\u1e4d\u1e4f\u1e51\u1e53\u1e55\u1e57\u1e59\u1e5b\u1e5d\u1e5f\u1e61\u1e63\u1e65\u1e67\u1e69\u1e6b\u1e6d\u1e6f\u1e71\u1e73\u1e75\u1e77\u1e79\u1e7b\u1e7d\u1e7f\u1e81\u1e83\u1e85\u1e87\u1e89\u1e8b\u1e8d\u1e8f\u1e91\u1e93\u1e95-\u1e9b\u1ea1\u1ea3\u1ea5\u1ea7\u1ea9\u1eab\u1ead\u1eaf\u1eb1\u1eb3\u1eb5\u1eb7\u1eb9\u1ebb\u1ebd\u1ebf\u1ec1\u1ec3\u1ec5\u1ec7\u1ec9\u1ecb\u1ecd\u1ecf\u1ed1\u1ed3\u1ed5\u1ed7\u1ed9\u1edb\u1edd\u1edf\u1ee1\u1ee3\u1ee5\u1ee7\u1ee9\u1eeb\u1eed\u1eef\u1ef1\u1ef3\u1ef5\u1ef7\u1ef9\u1f00-\u1f07\u1f10-\u1f15\u1f20-\u1f27\u1f30-\u1f37\u1f40-\u1f45\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f60-\u1f67\u1f70-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1f87\u1f90-\u1f97\u1fa0-\u1fa7\u1fb0-\u1fb4\u1fb6\u1fb7\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6\u1fc7\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6\u1fd7\u1fe0-\u1fe7\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6\u1ff7\u2071\u207f\u210a\u210e\u210f\u2113\u212f\u2134\u2139\u213c\u213d\u2146-\u2149\u214e\u2184\u2c30-\u2c5e\u2c61\u2c65\u2c66\u2c68\u2c6a\u2c6c\u2c74\u2c76\u2c77\u2c81\u2c83\u2c85\u2c87\u2c89\u2c8b\u2c8d\u2c8f\u2c91\u2c93\u2c95\u2c97\u2c99\u2c9b\u2c9d\u2c9f\u2ca1\u2ca3\u2ca5\u2ca7\u2ca9\u2cab\u2cad\u2caf\u2cb1\u2cb3\u2cb5\u2cb7\u2cb9\u2cbb\u2cbd\u2cbf\u2cc1\u2cc3\u2cc5\u2cc7\u2cc9\u2ccb\u2ccd\u2ccf\u2cd1\u2cd3\u2cd5\u2cd7\u2cd9\u2cdb\u2cdd\u2cdf\u2ce1\u2ce3\u2ce4\u2d00-\u2d25\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\uff41-\uff5a',
    Lm:'\u02b0-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ee\u037a\u0559\u0640\u06e5\u06e6\u07f4\u07f5\u07fa\u0e46\u0ec6\u10fc\u17d7\u1843\u1d2c-\u1d61\u1d78\u1d9b-\u1dbf\u2090-\u2094\u2d6f\u3005\u3031-\u3035\u303b\u309d\u309e\u30fc-\u30fe\ua015\ua717-\ua71a\uff70\uff9e\uff9f',
    Lo:'\u01bb\u01c0-\u01c3\u0294\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0621-\u063a\u0641-\u064a\u066e\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5\u06ee\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u076d\u0780-\u07a5\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u0904-\u0939\u093d\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u097b-\u097f\u0985-\u098c\u098f\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd\u09ce\u09dc\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36\u0a38\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd\u0ad0\u0ae0\u0ae1\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d\u0b5c\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9e\u0b9f\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb9\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c33\u0c35-\u0c39\u0c60\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd\u0cde\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d28\u0d2a-\u0d39\u0d60\u0d61\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e45\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2\u0eb3\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0edc\u0edd\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6a\u0f88-\u0f8b\u1000-\u1021\u1023-\u1027\u1029\u102a\u1050-\u1055\u10d0-\u10fa\u1100-\u1159\u115f-\u11a2\u11a8-\u11f9\u1200-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12d6\u12d8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135a\u1380-\u138f\u13a0-\u13f4\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u1676\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17dc\u1820-\u1842\u1844-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u1900-\u191c\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19a9\u19c1-\u19c7\u1a00-\u1a16\u1b05-\u1b33\u1b45-\u1b4b\u2135-\u2138\u2d30-\u2d65\u2d80-\u2d96\u2da0-\u2da6\u2da8-\u2dae\u2db0-\u2db6\u2db8-\u2dbe\u2dc0-\u2dc6\u2dc8-\u2dce\u2dd0-\u2dd6\u2dd8-\u2dde\u3006\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30ff\u3105-\u312c\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31b7\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400\u4db5\u4e00\u9fbb\ua000-\ua014\ua016-\ua48c\ua800\ua801\ua803-\ua805\ua807-\ua80a\ua80c-\ua822\ua840-\ua873\uac00\ud7a3\uf900-\ufa2d\ufa30-\ufa6a\ufa70-\ufad9\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e\ufb40\ufb41\ufb43\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff66-\uff6f\uff71-\uff9d\uffa0-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc',
    Lt:'\u01c5\u01c8\u01cb\u01f2\u1f88-\u1f8f\u1f98-\u1f9f\u1fa8-\u1faf\u1fbc\u1fcc\u1ffc',
    Lu:'\u0041-\u005a\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00de\u0100\u0102\u0104\u0106\u0108\u010a\u010c\u010e\u0110\u0112\u0114\u0116\u0118\u011a\u011c\u011e\u0120\u0122\u0124\u0126\u0128\u012a\u012c\u012e\u0130\u0132\u0134\u0136\u0139\u013b\u013d\u013f\u0141\u0143\u0145\u0147\u014a\u014c\u014e\u0150\u0152\u0154\u0156\u0158\u015a\u015c\u015e\u0160\u0162\u0164\u0166\u0168\u016a\u016c\u016e\u0170\u0172\u0174\u0176\u0178\u0179\u017b\u017d\u0181\u0182\u0184\u0186\u0187\u0189-\u018b\u018e-\u0191\u0193\u0194\u0196-\u0198\u019c\u019d\u019f\u01a0\u01a2\u01a4\u01a6\u01a7\u01a9\u01ac\u01ae\u01af\u01b1-\u01b3\u01b5\u01b7\u01b8\u01bc\u01c4\u01c7\u01ca\u01cd\u01cf\u01d1\u01d3\u01d5\u01d7\u01d9\u01db\u01de\u01e0\u01e2\u01e4\u01e6\u01e8\u01ea\u01ec\u01ee\u01f1\u01f4\u01f6-\u01f8\u01fa\u01fc\u01fe\u0200\u0202\u0204\u0206\u0208\u020a\u020c\u020e\u0210\u0212\u0214\u0216\u0218\u021a\u021c\u021e\u0220\u0222\u0224\u0226\u0228\u022a\u022c\u022e\u0230\u0232\u023a\u023b\u023d\u023e\u0241\u0243-\u0246\u0248\u024a\u024c\u024e\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c\u038e\u038f\u0391-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03ab\u03d2-\u03d4\u03d8\u03da\u03dc\u03de\u03e0\u03e2\u03e4\u03e6\u03e8\u03ea\u03ec\u03ee\u03f4\u03f7\u03f9\u03fa\u03fd-\u042f\u0460\u0462\u0464\u0466\u0468\u046a\u046c\u046e\u0470\u0472\u0474\u0476\u0478\u047a\u047c\u047e\u0480\u048a\u048c\u048e\u0490\u0492\u0494\u0496\u0498\u049a\u049c\u049e\u04a0\u04a2\u04a4\u04a6\u04a8\u04aa\u04ac\u04ae\u04b0\u04b2\u04b4\u04b6\u04b8\u04ba\u04bc\u04be\u04c0\u04c1\u04c3\u04c5\u04c7\u04c9\u04cb\u04cd\u04d0\u04d2\u04d4\u04d6\u04d8\u04da\u04dc\u04de\u04e0\u04e2\u04e4\u04e6\u04e8\u04ea\u04ec\u04ee\u04f0\u04f2\u04f4\u04f6\u04f8\u04fa\u04fc\u04fe\u0500\u0502\u0504\u0506\u0508\u050a\u050c\u050e\u0510\u0512\u0531-\u0556\u10a0-\u10c5\u1e00\u1e02\u1e04\u1e06\u1e08\u1e0a\u1e0c\u1e0e\u1e10\u1e12\u1e14\u1e16\u1e18\u1e1a\u1e1c\u1e1e\u1e20\u1e22\u1e24\u1e26\u1e28\u1e2a\u1e2c\u1e2e\u1e30\u1e32\u1e34\u1e36\u1e38\u1e3a\u1e3c\u1e3e\u1e40\u1e42\u1e44\u1e46\u1e48\u1e4a\u1e4c\u1e4e\u1e50\u1e52\u1e54\u1e56\u1e58\u1e5a\u1e5c\u1e5e\u1e60\u1e62\u1e64\u1e66\u1e68\u1e6a\u1e6c\u1e6e\u1e70\u1e72\u1e74\u1e76\u1e78\u1e7a\u1e7c\u1e7e\u1e80\u1e82\u1e84\u1e86\u1e88\u1e8a\u1e8c\u1e8e\u1e90\u1e92\u1e94\u1ea0\u1ea2\u1ea4\u1ea6\u1ea8\u1eaa\u1eac\u1eae\u1eb0\u1eb2\u1eb4\u1eb6\u1eb8\u1eba\u1ebc\u1ebe\u1ec0\u1ec2\u1ec4\u1ec6\u1ec8\u1eca\u1ecc\u1ece\u1ed0\u1ed2\u1ed4\u1ed6\u1ed8\u1eda\u1edc\u1ede\u1ee0\u1ee2\u1ee4\u1ee6\u1ee8\u1eea\u1eec\u1eee\u1ef0\u1ef2\u1ef4\u1ef6\u1ef8\u1f08-\u1f0f\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f28-\u1f2f\u1f38-\u1f3f\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f59\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5f\u1f68-\u1f6f\u1fb8-\u1fbb\u1fc8-\u1fcb\u1fd8-\u1fdb\u1fe8-\u1fec\u1ff8-\u1ffb\u2102\u2107\u210b-\u210d\u2110-\u2112\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u2130-\u2133\u213e\u213f\u2145\u2183\u2c00-\u2c2e\u2c60\u2c62-\u2c64\u2c67\u2c69\u2c6b\u2c75\u2c80\u2c82\u2c84\u2c86\u2c88\u2c8a\u2c8c\u2c8e\u2c90\u2c92\u2c94\u2c96\u2c98\u2c9a\u2c9c\u2c9e\u2ca0\u2ca2\u2ca4\u2ca6\u2ca8\u2caa\u2cac\u2cae\u2cb0\u2cb2\u2cb4\u2cb6\u2cb8\u2cba\u2cbc\u2cbe\u2cc0\u2cc2\u2cc4\u2cc6\u2cc8\u2cca\u2ccc\u2cce\u2cd0\u2cd2\u2cd4\u2cd6\u2cd8\u2cda\u2cdc\u2cde\u2ce0\u2ce2\uff21-\uff3a',
    Mc:'\u0903\u093e-\u0940\u0949-\u094c\u0982\u0983\u09be-\u09c0\u09c7\u09c8\u09cb\u09cc\u09d7\u0a03\u0a3e-\u0a40\u0a83\u0abe-\u0ac0\u0ac9\u0acb\u0acc\u0b02\u0b03\u0b3e\u0b40\u0b47\u0b48\u0b4b\u0b4c\u0b57\u0bbe\u0bbf\u0bc1\u0bc2\u0bc6-\u0bc8\u0bca-\u0bcc\u0bd7\u0c01-\u0c03\u0c41-\u0c44\u0c82\u0c83\u0cbe\u0cc0-\u0cc4\u0cc7\u0cc8\u0cca\u0ccb\u0cd5\u0cd6\u0d02\u0d03\u0d3e-\u0d40\u0d46-\u0d48\u0d4a-\u0d4c\u0d57\u0d82\u0d83\u0dcf-\u0dd1\u0dd8-\u0ddf\u0df2\u0df3\u0f3e\u0f3f\u0f7f\u102c\u1031\u1038\u1056\u1057\u17b6\u17be-\u17c5\u17c7\u17c8\u1923-\u1926\u1929-\u192b\u1930\u1931\u1933-\u1938\u19b0-\u19c0\u19c8\u19c9\u1a19-\u1a1b\u1b04\u1b35\u1b3b\u1b3d-\u1b41\u1b43\u1b44\ua802\ua823\ua824\ua827]',
    Me:'\u0488\u0489\u06de\u20dd-\u20e0\u20e2-\u20e4',
    Mn:'\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0486\u0591-\u05bd\u05bf\u05c1\u05c2\u05c4\u05c5\u05c7\u0610-\u0615\u064b-\u065e\u0670\u06d6-\u06dc\u06df-\u06e4\u06e7\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ed\u0711\u0730-\u074a\u07a6-\u07b0\u07eb-\u07f3\u0901\u0902\u093c\u0941-\u0948\u094d\u0951-\u0954\u0962\u0963\u0981\u09bc\u09c1-\u09c4\u09cd\u09e2\u09e3\u0a01\u0a02\u0a3c\u0a41\u0a42\u0a47\u0a48\u0a4b-\u0a4d\u0a70\u0a71\u0a81\u0a82\u0abc\u0ac1-\u0ac5\u0ac7\u0ac8\u0acd\u0ae2\u0ae3\u0b01\u0b3c\u0b3f\u0b41-\u0b43\u0b4d\u0b56\u0b82\u0bc0\u0bcd\u0c3e-\u0c40\u0c46-\u0c48\u0c4a-\u0c4d\u0c55\u0c56\u0cbc\u0cbf\u0cc6\u0ccc\u0ccd\u0ce2\u0ce3\u0d41-\u0d43\u0d4d\u0dca\u0dd2-\u0dd4\u0dd6\u0e31\u0e34-\u0e3a\u0e47-\u0e4e\u0eb1\u0eb4-\u0eb9\u0ebb\u0ebc\u0ec8-\u0ecd\u0f18\u0f19\u0f35\u0f37\u0f39\u0f71-\u0f7e\u0f80-\u0f84\u0f86\u0f87\u0f90-\u0f97\u0f99-\u0fbc\u0fc6\u102d-\u1030\u1032\u1036\u1037\u1039\u1058\u1059\u135f\u1712-\u1714\u1732-\u1734\u1752\u1753\u1772\u1773\u17b7-\u17bd\u17c6\u17c9-\u17d3\u17dd\u180b-\u180d\u18a9\u1920-\u1922\u1927\u1928\u1932\u1939-\u193b\u1a17\u1a18\u1b00-\u1b03\u1b34\u1b36-\u1b3a\u1b3c\u1b42\u1b6b-\u1b73\u1dc0-\u1dca\u1dfe\u1dff\u20d0-\u20dc\u20e1\u20e5-\u20ef\u302a-\u302f\u3099\u309a\ua806\ua80b\ua825\ua826\ufb1e\ufe00-\ufe0f\ufe20-\ufe23',
    Nd:'\u0030-\u0039\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9\u07c0-\u07c9\u0966-\u096f\u09e6-\u09ef\u0a66-\u0a6f\u0ae6-\u0aef\u0b66-\u0b6f\u0be6-\u0bef\u0c66-\u0c6f\u0ce6-\u0cef\u0d66-\u0d6f\u0e50-\u0e59\u0ed0-\u0ed9\u0f20-\u0f29\u1040-\u1049\u17e0-\u17e9\u1810-\u1819\u1946-\u194f\u19d0-\u19d9\u1b50-\u1b59\uff10-\uff19',
    Nl:'\u16ee-\u16f0\u2160-\u2182\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303a',
    No:'\u00b2\u00b3\u00b9\u00bc-\u00be\u09f4-\u09f9\u0bf0-\u0bf2\u0f2a-\u0f33\u1369-\u137c\u17f0-\u17f9\u2070\u2074-\u2079\u2080-\u2089\u2153-\u215f\u2460-\u249b\u24ea-\u24ff\u2776-\u2793\u2cfd\u3192-\u3195\u3220-\u3229\u3251-\u325f\u3280-\u3289\u32b1-\u32bf',
    Pc:'\u005f\u203f\u2040\u2054\ufe33\ufe34\ufe4d-\ufe4f\uff3f',
    Pd:'\u002d\u058a\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2e17\u301c\u3030\u30a0\ufe31\ufe32\ufe58\ufe63\uff0d',
    Pe:'\u0029\u005d\u007d\u0f3b\u0f3d\u169c\u2046\u207e\u208e\u232a\u2769\u276b\u276d\u276f\u2771\u2773\u2775\u27c6\u27e7\u27e9\u27eb\u2984\u2986\u2988\u298a\u298c\u298e\u2990\u2992\u2994\u2996\u2998\u29d9\u29db\u29fd\u3009\u300b\u300d\u300f\u3011\u3015\u3017\u3019\u301b\u301e\u301f\ufd3f\ufe18\ufe36\ufe38\ufe3a\ufe3c\ufe3e\ufe40\ufe42\ufe44\ufe48\ufe5a\ufe5c\ufe5e\uff09\uff3d\uff5d\uff60\uff63',
    Pf:'\u00bb\u2019\u201d\u203a\u2e03\u2e05\u2e0a\u2e0d\u2e1d',
    Pi:'\u00ab\u2018\u201b\u201c\u201f\u2039\u2e02\u2e04\u2e09\u2e0c\u2e1c',
    Po:'\u0021-\u0023\u0025-\u0027\u002a\u002c\u002e\u002f\u003a\u003b\u003f\u0040\u005c\u00a1\u00b7\u00bf\u037e\u0387\u055a-\u055f\u0589\u05be\u05c0\u05c3\u05c6\u05f3\u05f4\u060c\u060d\u061b\u061e\u061f\u066a-\u066d\u06d4\u0700-\u070d\u07f7-\u07f9\u0964\u0965\u0970\u0df4\u0e4f\u0e5a\u0e5b\u0f04-\u0f12\u0f85\u0fd0\u0fd1\u104a-\u104f\u10fb\u1361-\u1368\u166d\u166e\u16eb-\u16ed\u1735\u1736\u17d4-\u17d6\u17d8-\u17da\u1800-\u1805\u1807-\u180a\u1944\u1945\u19de\u19df\u1a1e\u1a1f\u1b5a-\u1b60\u2016\u2017\u2020-\u2027\u2030-\u2038\u203b-\u203e\u2041-\u2043\u2047-\u2051\u2053\u2055-\u205e\u2cf9-\u2cfc\u2cfe\u2cff\u2e00\u2e01\u2e06-\u2e08\u2e0b\u2e0e-\u2e16\u3001-\u3003\u303d\u30fb\ua874-\ua877\ufe10-\ufe16\ufe19\ufe30\ufe45\ufe46\ufe49-\ufe4c\ufe50-\ufe52\ufe54-\ufe57\ufe5f-\ufe61\ufe68\ufe6a\ufe6b\uff01-\uff03\uff05-\uff07\uff0a\uff0c\uff0e\uff0f\uff1a\uff1b\uff1f\uff20\uff3c\uff61\uff64\uff65',
    Ps:'\u0028\u005b\u007b\u0f3a\u0f3c\u169b\u201a\u201e\u2045\u207d\u208d\u2329\u2768\u276a\u276c\u276e\u2770\u2772\u2774\u27c5\u27e6\u27e8\u27ea\u2983\u2985\u2987\u2989\u298b\u298d\u298f\u2991\u2993\u2995\u2997\u29d8\u29da\u29fc\u3008\u300a\u300c\u300e\u3010\u3014\u3016\u3018\u301a\u301d\ufd3e\ufe17\ufe35\ufe37\ufe39\ufe3b\ufe3d\ufe3f\ufe41\ufe43\ufe47\ufe59\ufe5b\ufe5d\uff08\uff3b\uff5b\uff5f\uff62',
    Sc:'\u0024\u00a2-\u00a5\u060b\u09f2\u09f3\u0af1\u0bf9\u0e3f\u17db\u20a0-\u20b5\ufdfc\ufe69\uff04\uffe0\uffe1\uffe5\uffe6',
    Sk:'\u005e\u0060\u00a8\u00af\u00b4\u00b8\u02c2-\u02c5\u02d2-\u02df\u02e5-\u02ed\u02ef-\u02ff\u0374\u0375\u0384\u0385\u1fbd\u1fbf-\u1fc1\u1fcd-\u1fcf\u1fdd-\u1fdf\u1fed-\u1fef\u1ffd\u1ffe\u309b\u309c\ua700-\ua716\ua720\ua721\uff3e\uff40\uffe3',
    Sm:'\u002b\u003c-\u003e\u007c\u007e\u00ac\u00b1\u00d7\u00f7\u03f6\u2044\u2052\u207a-\u207c\u208a-\u208c\u2140-\u2144\u214b\u2190-\u2194\u219a\u219b\u21a0\u21a3\u21a6\u21ae\u21ce\u21cf\u21d2\u21d4\u21f4-\u22ff\u2308-\u230b\u2320\u2321\u237c\u239b-\u23b3\u23dc-\u23e1\u25b7\u25c1\u25f8-\u25ff\u266f\u27c0-\u27c4\u27c7-\u27ca\u27d0-\u27e5\u27f0-\u27ff\u2900-\u2982\u2999-\u29d7\u29dc-\u29fb\u29fe-\u2aff\ufb29\ufe62\ufe64-\ufe66\uff0b\uff1c-\uff1e\uff5c\uff5e\uffe2\uffe9-\uffec',
    So:'\u00a6\u00a7\u00a9\u00ae\u00b0\u00b6\u0482\u060e\u060f\u06e9\u06fd\u06fe\u07f6\u09fa\u0b70\u0bf3-\u0bf8\u0bfa\u0cf1\u0cf2\u0f01-\u0f03\u0f13-\u0f17\u0f1a-\u0f1f\u0f34\u0f36\u0f38\u0fbe-\u0fc5\u0fc7-\u0fcc\u0fcf\u1360\u1390-\u1399\u1940\u19e0-\u19ff\u1b61-\u1b6a\u1b74-\u1b7c\u2100\u2101\u2103-\u2106\u2108\u2109\u2114\u2116-\u2118\u211e-\u2123\u2125\u2127\u2129\u212e\u213a\u213b\u214a\u214c\u214d\u2195-\u2199\u219c-\u219f\u21a1\u21a2\u21a4\u21a5\u21a7-\u21ad\u21af-\u21cd\u21d0\u21d1\u21d3\u21d5-\u21f3\u2300-\u2307\u230c-\u231f\u2322-\u2328\u232b-\u237b\u237d-\u239a\u23b4-\u23db\u23e2-\u23e7\u2400-\u2426\u2440-\u244a\u249c-\u24e9\u2500-\u25b6\u25b8-\u25c0\u25c2-\u25f7\u2600-\u266e\u2670-\u269c\u26a0-\u26b2\u2701-\u2704\u2706-\u2709\u270c-\u2727\u2729-\u274b\u274d\u274f-\u2752\u2756\u2758-\u275e\u2761-\u2767\u2794\u2798-\u27af\u27b1-\u27be\u2800-\u28ff\u2b00-\u2b1a\u2b20-\u2b23\u2ce5-\u2cea\u2e80-\u2e99\u2e9b-\u2ef3\u2f00-\u2fd5\u2ff0-\u2ffb\u3004\u3012\u3013\u3020\u3036\u3037\u303e\u303f\u3190\u3191\u3196-\u319f\u31c0-\u31cf\u3200-\u321e\u322a-\u3243\u3250\u3260-\u327f\u328a-\u32b0\u32c0-\u32fe\u3300-\u33ff\u4dc0-\u4dff\ua490-\ua4c6\ua828-\ua82b\ufdfd\uffe4\uffe8\uffed\uffee\ufffc\ufffd',
    Zl:'\u2028',
    Zp:'\u2029',
    ZZ:'\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000',
    Zs:'\u0020\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000'
};

Unicode.C = Unicode.Cc 
            + Unicode.Cf 
            + Unicode.Cs 
            + Unicode.Co ;
            //+ Unicode.Cn ; //This is not defined.

Unicode.L = Unicode.Lu 
            + Unicode.Ll 
            + Unicode.Lt 
            + Unicode.Lm 
            + Unicode.Mn    //Added 2014-05-29 due to some letters in names not being recognized.
                            //This is where accent marks are individually combined instead of using an explicit character.
            + Unicode.Lo ;

Unicode.LC= Unicode.Lu 
            + Unicode.Ll 
            + Unicode.Lt ;

Unicode.M = Unicode.Mn 
            + Unicode.Mc 
            + Unicode.Me ;

Unicode.N = Unicode.Nd 
            + Unicode.Nl 
            + Unicode.No ;

Unicode.P = Unicode.Pc 
            + Unicode.Pd 
            + Unicode.Ps 
            + Unicode.Pe 
            + Unicode.Pi 
            + Unicode.Pf 
            + Unicode.Po ;

Unicode.S = Unicode.Sm 
            + Unicode.Sc 
            + Unicode.Sk 
            + Unicode.So ;

Unicode.Z = Unicode.Zs 
            + Unicode.Zl 
            + Unicode.Zp ;

//Not in Unicode spec:
Unicode.w = '_'
            + Unicode.L
            + Unicode.N ;

    //A Unicode based word boundry built with non-capturing parentheses
Unicode.b = '(?:[' + Unicode.w + '](?:[^' + Unicode.w +']|$)'
            + '|(?:^|[^' + Unicode.w + '])[' + Unicode.w +']'
            + ')' ;

    //A Unicode based word boundry build with non-capturing parentheses
Unicode.bOut = '(?=[^' + Unicode.w +']|$)';

    //A Unicode based word boundry build with non-capturing parentheses
    //JavaScript does not have a non-consuming look-behind.
    //This makes a direct replacement for \b not possible as we may consume
    // part of the string to make this test.
Unicode.bIn = '(?:^|[^' + Unicode.w + '])';

    //A possible work-around is to use a capture and replace it.
Unicode.bInCapture = '(?:^|([^' + Unicode.w + ']))';

    //A Unicode based non-word boundry build with non-capturing parentheses
Unicode.B = '(?:[' + Unicode.w + '][' + Unicode.w +']'
        + '|[^' + Unicode.w + '][^' + Unicode.w +']'
        + ')' ;

Unicode.d = Unicode.N ;
Unicode.uppercaseRegex      = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.Lu + "]", "");
Unicode.lowercaseRegex      = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.Ll + "]", "");
Unicode.titlecaseRegex      = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.Lt + "]", "");
Unicode.wordCharRegex       = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.w + "]", "");
Unicode.nonWordCharRegex    = new RegExp("[^" + Unicode.w + "]", "");
Unicode.letterAndSpaceRegEx = new RegExp("[^" + Unicode.L + Unicode.Zs + "]", "");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the npm package so I think the unicode plugin is automatically included. I'm curious, does xregexp have an equivalent to the String.match() function or do I need to implement a loop with the .Exec() or .ForEach() functions?

Comment: From the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) page: "XRegExp regexes compile to native RegExp objects". This means that you could use it anywhere you would a normal `RegExp`, including with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: Note that @Makyen's code example does not interpret many foreign characters as "word" chars, e.g., Chinese.

Comment: @BenWheeler You may want to [read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998519/net-regex-what-is-the-word-character-w).