# Javascript regex for catching special XSS lines

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension, xss

I have this special XSS line I am trying to catch/detect with a regex. I have tried multiple ones, none seems to work. Although online regex test sites catch it, when I try it in actual code, it does not work.

Here is thee special line that I need to catch with regex:

```
<<​ ​​ ​ScRiPT​ ​​ ​​ ​>alert("XSS");//<</​ ​ScRiPT​ ​​ ​>
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
/[<]*<\s*script\s*>.*[/]*[<]*<\s*\/\s*script\s*>/ig;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there meant to be a closing </script>? Also, when pasting into regexer, that text has a bunch of odd invisible characters that aren't normal space characters. I'm not sure what you pasted is correct.

Comment: This is the first mistake one can do whenever he tries to apply security measurements. You should not accept any tag if your content is not allow that. for example I can bypass  your regex entirely just by using other tag.

`<img src="" onerror="alert(1)"/>`  will alert(1).

Comment: Why don't you use CSP?

Comment: You need to tell us *exactly* what you desire to detect & *exactly* what you desire to reject. In this instance, the text you are attempting to detect contains a bunch of [Zero Width Space (`\u200B`) characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm). You will need to include those along with the `\s`. However, you will probably want to go with including any possible [Unicode space character in your RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/280712/3773011). If you want to specifically select some groups of characters, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26135188) has some.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace class (`\s`) [doesn't contain](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) zero-width space. So you have to specify that explicitly:

```
/[<]*<[\s\u200B]*script[\s\u200B]*>.*[/]*[<]*<[\s\u200B]*\/[\s\u200B]*script[\s\u200B]*>/ig;
```

Here is a snippet of it working:

```js
var str = "<<​ ​​ ​ScRiPT​ ​​ ​​ ​>alert(\"XSS\");//<</​ ​ScRiPT​ ​​ ​>";
var regex = /[<]*<[\s\u200B]*script[\s\u200B]*>.*[/]*[<]*<[\s\u200B]*\/[\s\u200B]*script[\s\u200B]*>/ig;
document.write("Regex matched: " + regex.test(str));
```