# Remove non-word characters and leading numbers from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text field which feeds into a label through code. As the user types text into the field, it will automatically parse the text, and strip out non-word characters from the text and place it into the label.

```
private void text_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    label.Content = Regex.Replace(text.Text, @"[^\w]", "").ToLower();
}
```

However, I have another constraint to this label field, and I can't figure out how to do it. The current RegEx I have makes it so the label can only have lowercase word characters. However, I also need to make sure the first character in the label is not a number. I have tried `^[^A-Za-z][^\w]`, but that isn't working. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Fixed; either way, still doesn't work.

Comment: `The current RegEx I have makes it so the label can only have lowercase word characters` which regex does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original problem says "replace {an English letter} with.." and not "replace {a number} with.."; after the update it is still problematic because it considers the two operations to be compound - it will replace the non-A-Z *only* if it is not followed by a word character.

Compare with rewriting it as so:

```
var filtered = text.Text;
filtered = Regex.Replace(filtered, @"\W+", "");   // trim non-word characters
filtered = Regex.Replace(filtered, @"^\d+", "");  // remove number(s) at start

label.Content = filtered.ToLower();
```

Do note that, by default, in C#/.NET the [escapes like `\w`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998519/net-regex-what-is-the-word-character-w) and `\d` (and their opposites) are Unicode-aware. This makes them different from JavaScript / PCRE / Java / perl, etc., which are more English-centric.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I didn't think to have the requirements on two lines instead of one.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod I like regular expressions .. but only in small bites. This could be written as a single regular expression with the use of an alternation (`@"^\d+|\W+"`), I chose the above mostly to show a point.

Comment: Yeah. I use a TON of regex in my work... become very good at them. The issue for me was figuring out how C# works, not the regex.