# Regular expression to space in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I need a help regarding regular expression.

I have to match string like this: "dãasc abd"

Pattern that i have used:

```
([^\u0000-\u007F] |\\w|^[a-zA-Z0-9-\\s]*$)+
```

but this pattern does not allow whitle spaces in two strings

Please help me for find out correct pattern for this kind of string.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to match... That reges seems to be a mashup of things...

Comment: Maybe `@"^\w+(?:[-\s]\w+)*$"`? It will match `Как`, `Как дела`, `Как-никак`, `Ростов-на-Дону`. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a%5b-%5cs%5d%5cw%2b%29*%5cr%3f%24&i=%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%0d%0a%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba+%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%0d%0a%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%0d%0a%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83&o=m).

Comment: I want to match swedish characters so I put  [^\u0000-\u007F]  this pattern.I want to match  "dãa3sc abd" this type of string.

Comment: Yes, `\w` will match any alphabet letters. See, it also matches Russian words. What are the exact requirements?

Comment: That isn't what that regex is matching... It is matching non-ascii characters followed by a space (`[^\u0000-\u007F] `) OR any word character (that is any letter with or without diacritics or any number, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2998550/613130) or a whole string composed only from letters, numbers and spaces.

Comment: Try `^(\\w||\\s)+$`

Comment: Besides, the requirements, please also post the code you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It's matching but  it is not supported by java script as I'm getting client side validation message which vanishes within second so to  avoid that I have used [^\u0000-\u007F].

Comment: I'm using it in MVC as attribute to property.Property   [RegularExpression(RegexKeys.AllLanguageCharacters , ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid string,no special characters allowed")]

Comment: I also don't want to allow underscore

Comment: @Shubh's Ok, try with `^([A-Za-z0-9]|\\s|[^\u0000-\u007F)+$`

Comment: Does it mean the regex pattern should also be compatible with JavaScript regex engine? Is it also run on the client side?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes.It is working fine now.Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew..How can I accept your answer?I'm not finding any option to up vote..

Comment: Is the `@"^\w+(?:[-\s]\w+)*$"` pattern working for you? But it accepts underscores. In order to not match them you need `@"^[\w-[_]]+(?:[-\s][\w-[_]]+)*$"` - but that will only work on the server side, in .NET.

Comment: No @"^\w+(?:[-\s]\w+)*$" pattern not working for me as it accepts underscore. but  ^([A-Za-z0-9]|\\s|[^\u0000-\u007F)+$ pattern worked on both client and server side

Comment: I think what worked was `^([A-Za-z0-9]|\\s|[^\u0000-\u007F])+$`

Comment: @xanatos: If you wish, you may post your above regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]|\\s|[^\u0000-\u007F])+$
```

It means that the string must be entirely composed of ASCII letters or numbers `[A-Za-z0-9]` or spaces `\\s` or non-ASCII characters `[^\u0000-\u007F]` (it means characters outside the `00-7F` range, so `>7F`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove one slash in your regex, where you define white space:

Try this:

```
@"([^\u0000-\u007F]|\s|[a-zA-Z0-9-])+"
```