# Regex to find a string that does not contain a space while matching other conditions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, spaces

I have a bunch of strings that may contains certain patterns. Specifically, the following 3.

1. Starts with `(-` followed by 10 digits followed by `)`.

   E.g.:

   > (-1234567890)
2. Starts with `(`, ends with `)`, and may contain 1 or more characters, but **NO** spaces.

   E.g.:

   > (ABC) or (AF33) or (2345)
3. Starts with `(`, ends with `)`, and may contain 1 or more characters, **INCLUDING** spaces.

   E.g.:

   > (Some string)

The strings I work with may contain zero or more of the patterns above. My requirement is to match **ONLY** the second one from above in a given string, and I'd like to be able to use `Regex` class in C#.

For example, let's say following are five different strings I have.

> This is some random text.
>
> This is some (ABC) random (-1234567890) text.
>
> This is some (XY12) random (-1234567890) text.
>
> This is some (Contains space) random (-1234567890) text.
>
> This is some () random text.

My `Regex` should match **only the 2nd and 3rd strings** from the above list.

So far, I've managed to write this following Regex, which excludes strings 1 and 5.

```
.*\((?!\-).+\).*
```

This matches 2nd, 3rd, **AND** 4th strings above. Now I'm not sure how I can get it to exclude the 4th, one which contains spaces inside parenthesis. I know that `\S` detects whitespaces, but how can I tell it to detect strings that do not contain spaces only within the parenthesis that don't contain a `-` after the first `(`?

**EDIT 1:**

There will never be nested parenthesis in my strings.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a [Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/CfjSgb/1/).

Comment: whats your char set? is it ascii only? is it possible to have another ( inside ()? like (\\()

Comment: Both ASCII and UTF8 would be preferable, but I'd be happy even with just ASCII if it's too difficult to incorporate both.

Comment: And no, there will never be nested parenthesis.

Comment: Something simple like [`.*?\(\w+\).*`](https://regex101.com/r/FKV8fl/1) would be sufficient, wouldn't it.

Comment: I think you need [`@"^[^()]*(?:\(([^\s()]+)\)[^()]*)+$"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%28%5b%5e%5cs%28%29%5d%2b%29%5c%29%5b%5e%28%29%5cn%5d*%29%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=This+is+some+random+text.%0d%0aThis+is+some+%28ABC%29+random+%28-1234567890%29+text.%0d%0aThis+is+some+%28XY12%29+random+%28-1234567890%29+text.%0d%0aThis+is+some+%28Contains+space%29+random+%28-1234567890%29+text.%0d%0aThis+is+some+%28%29+random+text.&o=m). If you need a whole string that contains the pattern, use `if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern)) { /*do something with s*/ }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.*\(\w+\).*
```

If you use above regex, second and third strings are matches only

.* all characters

( pharantesis

\w+ all word characters (at least one)

) pharantesis

.* all characters

Comment: That does seem to work, thanks! Can you please explain it, maybe breaking down? Especially the `(\w|\d)+` part?

Comment: `\w` will match any 'word character' (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998519/net-regex-what-is-the-word-character-w).  `\d` will match any numeric digit.  `(\w|\d)` will match a word character or a digit.  `(\w|\d)+` will match one or more of a word character or a digit.  After my edit I wonder if just `(\w)+` would work for that part since it seems that `\w` also matches digits.

Comment: @huck_cussler yes you right. I also notice that and fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\(([^- ]+[^ ]*)\)
```

should work

Explanation:

`[^- ]+` will first match one character that's neither `-` or    This will make sure it contains at least one character

Then `[^ ]*` will match 0 or more none white space characters

This will work for any char set