# How to cover international lowercase word characters in a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I cover all lowercase non-numeric word characters in a regex?

For example this would cover `Müller` for german umlauts

```
/[A-Z][a-zäöü-]+/g
```

...but what about french or spanish word characters? Is it possible to get those covered by a range or something like that?

The regex should NOT match a string which has multiple uppercase characters, like `DOntGetMe`. But it should match `McDonald`.

So I came up at the end with

```
/([A-Z][a-zäöü'-](?:[\w'-]+)?)/g
```

But it still don't cover french/spanish characters.

https://regex101.com/r/ofl4tj/2

*Match*

```
Smith
Müller
McDonald
O'Riley
Lee
Li
Manco-Johnson
```

*Don't match*

```
MIsspelled
ABC
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998519/net-regex-what-is-the-word-character-w

Comment: @Ctznkane525 That doesn't help. `/w` is covering uppercase characters. So `MIsspelled` would get matched - which should not.

Comment: Ud put the w after the capital a-z

Comment: I suspect the Unicode lowercase letters are the least trouble for you. Please explain the requirements for the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So mainly I just want to NOT match strings with multiple uppercase characters at the beginning: `ABC`, `MIsspelled` are wrong. All other words should match. Maybe this way should be easier??

Comment: Yes. Use [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/) and `"^\\p{Lu}+\\p{Ll}+$"` pattern for these strings. See a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2depr091/1/), update as necessary.

Comment: @user3142695 Did you check my answer below? Please see https://regex101.com/r/WNMvR4/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, but that would not match `O'Riley` or `McDonald`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a letter from English alphabet as beginning of word use a word boundary `\b` right before `[A-Z]`. Using [Unicode CLDR](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp) or [Mother E**](https://mothereff.in/regexpu), to match all lowercase letters from all languages (`\p{Ll}`) this would be the regex:

```
(?:[a-z\xB5\xDF-\xF6\xF8-\xFF\u0101\u0103\u0105\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u010F\u0111\u0113\u0115\u0117\u0119\u011B\u011D\u011F\u0121\u0123\u0125\u0127\u0129\u012B\u012D\u012F\u0131\u0133\u0135\u0137\u0138\u013A\u013C\u013E\u0140\u0142\u0144\u0146\u0148\u0149\u014B\u014D\u014F\u0151\u0153\u0155\u0157\u0159\u015B\u015D\u015F\u0161\u0163\u0165\u0167\u0169\u016B\u016D\u016F\u0171\u0173\u0175\u0177\u017A\u017C\u017E-\u0180\u0183\u0185\u0188\u018C\u018D\u0192\u0195\u0199-\u019B\u019E\u01A1\u01A3\u01A5\u01A8\u01AA\u01AB\u01AD\u01B0\u01B4\u01B6\u01B9\u01BA\u01BD-\u01BF\u01C6\u01C9\u01CC\u01CE\u01D0\u01D2\u01D4\u01D6\u01D8\u01DA\u01DC\u01DD\u01DF\u01E1\u01E3\u01E5\u01E7\u01E9\u01EB\u01ED\u01EF\u01F0\u01F3\u01F5\u01F9\u01FB\u01FD\u01FF\u0201\u0203\u0205\u0207\u0209\u020B\u020D\u020F\u0211\u0213\u0215\u0217\u0219\u021B\u021D\u021F\u0221\u0223\u0225\u0227\u0229\u022B\u022D\u022F\u0231\u0233-\u0239\u023C\u023F\u0240\u0242\u0247\u0249\u024B\u024D\u024F-\u0293\u0295-\u02AF\u0371\u0373\u0377\u037B-\u037D\u0390\u03AC-\u03CE\u03D0\u03D1\u03D5-\u03D7\u03D9\u03DB\u03DD\u03DF\u03E1\u03E3\u03E5\u03E7\u03E9\u03EB\u03ED\u03EF-\u03F3\u03F5\u03F8\u03FB\u03FC\u0430-\u045F\u0461\u0463\u0465\u0467\u0469\u046B\u046D\u046F\u0471\u0473\u0475\u0477\u0479\u047B\u047D\u047F\u0481\u048B\u048D\u048F\u0491\u0493\u0495\u0497\u0499\u049B\u049D\u049F\u04A1\u04A3\u04A5\u04A7\u04A9\u04AB\u04AD\u04AF\u04B1\u04B3\u04B5\u04B7\u04B9\u04BB\u04BD\u04BF\u04C2\u04C4\u04C6\u04C8\u04CA\u04CC\u04CE\u04CF\u04D1\u04D3\u04D5\u04D7\u04D9\u04DB\u04DD\u04DF\u04E1\u04E3\u04E5\u04E7\u04E9\u04EB\u04ED\u04EF\u04F1\u04F3\u04F5\u04F7\u04F9\u04FB\u04FD\u04FF\u0501\u0503\u0505\u0507\u0509\u050B\u050D\u050F\u0511\u0513\u0515\u0517\u0519\u051B\u051D\u051F\u0521\u0523\u0525\u0527\u0529\u052B\u052D\u052F\u0560-\u0588\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FD-\u10FF\u13F8-\u13FD\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D00-\u1D2B\u1D6B-\u1D77\u1D79-\u1D9A\u1E01\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u1E09\u1E0B\u1E0D\u1E0F\u1E11\u1E13\u1E15\u1E17\u1E19\u1E1B\u1E1D\u1E1F\u1E21\u1E23\u1E25\u1E27\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E2D\u1E2F\u1E31\u1E33\u1E35\u1E37\u1E39\u1E3B\u1E3D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u1E45\u1E47\u1E49\u1E4B\u1E4D\u1E4F\u1E51\u1E53\u1E55\u1E57\u1E59\u1E5B\u1E5D\u1E5F\u1E61\u1E63\u1E65\u1E67\u1E69\u1E6B\u1E6D\u1E6F\u1E71\u1E73\u1E75\u1E77\u1E79\u1E7B\u1E7D\u1E7F\u1E81\u1E83\u1E85\u1E87\u1E89\u1E8B\u1E8D\u1E8F\u1E91\u1E93\u1E95-\u1E9D\u1E9F\u1EA1\u1EA3\u1EA5\u1EA7\u1EA9\u1EAB\u1EAD\u1EAF\u1EB1\u1EB3\u1EB5\u1EB7\u1EB9\u1EBB\u1EBD\u1EBF\u1EC1\u1EC3\u1EC5\u1EC7\u1EC9\u1ECB\u1ECD\u1ECF\u1ED1\u1ED3\u1ED5\u1ED7\u1ED9\u1EDB\u1EDD\u1EDF\u1EE1\u1EE3\u1EE5\u1EE7\u1EE9\u1EEB\u1EED\u1EEF\u1EF1\u1EF3\u1EF5\u1EF7\u1EF9\u1EFB\u1EFD\u1EFF-\u1F07\u1F10-\u1F15\u1F20-\u1F27\u1F30-\u1F37\u1F40-\u1F45\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F60-\u1F67\u1F70-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1F87\u1F90-\u1F97\u1FA0-\u1FA7\u1FB0-\u1FB4\u1FB6\u1FB7\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6\u1FC7\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6\u1FD7\u1FE0-\u1FE7\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6\u1FF7\u210A\u210E\u210F\u2113\u212F\u2134\u2139\u213C\u213D\u2146-\u2149\u214E\u2184\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C61\u2C65\u2C66\u2C68\u2C6A\u2C6C\u2C71\u2C73\u2C74\u2C76-\u2C7B\u2C81\u2C83\u2C85\u2C87\u2C89\u2C8B\u2C8D\u2C8F\u2C91\u2C93\u2C95\u2C97\u2C99\u2C9B\u2C9D\u2C9F\u2CA1\u2CA3\u2CA5\u2CA7\u2CA9\u2CAB\u2CAD\u2CAF\u2CB1\u2CB3\u2CB5\u2CB7\u2CB9\u2CBB\u2CBD\u2CBF\u2CC1\u2CC3\u2CC5\u2CC7\u2CC9\u2CCB\u2CCD\u2CCF\u2CD1\u2CD3\u2CD5\u2CD7\u2CD9\u2CDB\u2CDD\u2CDF\u2CE1\u2CE3\u2CE4\u2CEC\u2CEE\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\uA641\uA643\uA645\uA647\uA649\uA64B\uA64D\uA64F\uA651\uA653\uA655\uA657\uA659\uA65B\uA65D\uA65F\uA661\uA663\uA665\uA667\uA669\uA66B\uA66D\uA681\uA683\uA685\uA687\uA689\uA68B\uA68D\uA68F\uA691\uA693\uA695\uA697\uA699\uA69B\uA723\uA725\uA727\uA729\uA72B\uA72D\uA72F-\uA731\uA733\uA735\uA737\uA739\uA73B\uA73D\uA73F\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA747\uA749\uA74B\uA74D\uA74F\uA751\uA753\uA755\uA757\uA759\uA75B\uA75D\uA75F\uA761\uA763\uA765\uA767\uA769\uA76B\uA76D\uA76F\uA771-\uA778\uA77A\uA77C\uA77F\uA781\uA783\uA785\uA787\uA78C\uA78E\uA791\uA793-\uA795\uA797\uA799\uA79B\uA79D\uA79F\uA7A1\uA7A3\uA7A5\uA7A7\uA7A9\uA7AF\uA7B5\uA7B7\uA7B9\uA7FA\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB60-\uAB65\uAB70-\uABBF\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFF41-\uFF5A]|\uD801[\uDC28-\uDC4F\uDCD8-\uDCFB]|\uD803[\uDCC0-\uDCF2]|\uD806[\uDCC0-\uDCDF]|\uD81B[\uDE60-\uDE7F]|\uD835[\uDC1A-\uDC33\uDC4E-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC67\uDC82-\uDC9B\uDCB6-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDCCF\uDCEA-\uDD03\uDD1E-\uDD37\uDD52-\uDD6B\uDD86-\uDD9F\uDDBA-\uDDD3\uDDEE-\uDE07\uDE22-\uDE3B\uDE56-\uDE6F\uDE8A-\uDEA5\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEE1\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF1B\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF55\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDF8F\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFC9\uDFCB]|\uD83A[\uDD22-\uDD43])
```

`\b` is not Unicode aware in JS so you can't use it for multi-byte letters - I'm not sure if you need it either. But if you do translate `\p{L}\p{D}` using above tools and use it in a negative lookahead `(?!...)` or simply do a `(?!\S)`. The latter is more general but most of times satisfies the needs.

Comment: That's how JS works. You can import libs like mentioned XRegExp but I wouldn't suggest if you only need to deal with a few regexes for Unicode properties or other advanced features. Current one is big but absolutely fine. BTW all current JS libs implement such big regexes for Unicode properties behind the scenes.