# How to find Unicode Pattern using Regex in Python3.7?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to find a Unicode pattern but it always returns an empty list [ ].
I have tried the same pattern in Kwrite and it worked fine.

I have tried \u \\u in place of \w but didn't work for me. Here Unicode string can be any Unicode string.

```
InputString=r"[[ਅਤੇ\CC_CCD]]_CCP"

Result = re.findall(r'[\[]+[\w]+\\\w+[\]]+[_]\w+',InputString,flags=re.U)

print(Result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an extra character `ੇ` between `ਤ` and `\` which cannot be matched by `\w+`. It's hex value is `0xA47` So, I have added `[\u0A47]` in the regex.

Try this Regex:

```
\[+\w+[\u0A47]\\\w+]]\w+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vv2Qzl/3)**

**Explanation:**

- `\[+` - matches 1+ occurrences of `[`
- `\w+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a [word character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998550/5331061)
- `[^\\]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character which is not `\`
- `\\` - matches `\`
- `\w+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a word character
- `]]` - matches `]]`
- `\w+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a word character

[**Python code**](https://regex101.com/r/vv2Qzl/3/codegen?language=python)

The words are from [Gurmukhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurmukhi_(Unicode_block)) language. The unicode range is `0A00 - 0A7F`. So you can also use the regex:

```
\[+[\u0A00-\u0A7F]+\\\w+]]\w+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vv2Qzl/6)**

Comment: this works, can explain it why need a '.' after \w. and if we have multiple patterns in a string it returns only first. Link (https://regex101.com/r/vv2Qzl/4)

Comment: @UMR See the full updated answer for the explanation.

Comment: @UMR See the 2nd regex I have posted in the answer. It will match all the gurmukhi characters.

Comment: Thanks, the Second one worked fine for me. It matched all the patterns from given text.