# Get string between two characters using regex in typescript

Tags: regex, typescript

I wan to extract the string from the below line of code

`span id="testing" This is testing span a id="test" link a`

from the above code I want to extract the id's alone using regex

eg: "testing", "test"

Comment: regex could simply be something like `"(\w+)"` if your identifiers are comprised only of "word characters" (letters, underscore)

Comment: I want to extract only the string between id=" "

Comment: No I mean I want to get string between id=" "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your identifiers are comprised of [word characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998519/net-regex-what-is-the-word-character-w/) only:

this regex works: `(?<=id=")\w+(?=")`. The full match is the id. However, this could cause compatibility issue in Safari, that doesn't support lookbehinds (`(?<= )`)

[Test it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zwdqIB/1)

You can also use capture groups with `id="(\w+)"`. The only captured group will be the id you're looking for.

[Test it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZWUyBS/1)

Comment: FYI. It's better to use capture groups since safari doesn't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `id="(\w+)"` as the regex.