# Check if specific word appears before other word using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if specific word appears before another word? If it appears it must not match, if doesn't appear it must match, there can be other words between them

Here is example string: `My name is Jack Brown`

I want to check if `name` word appears before `Jack`, here is my regex:

regex: `(?<!name)\b(Jack)\b`

but untortunately it works only when there is no any words between them, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to negate the `name` before `Jack`.

```
(?=^(?:(?!name).)*Jack.*$).*
```

##### Short Explanation

- `(?:(?!name).)*` Anything except the word `name`
- `Jack.*` Exact word `Jack` and other optional characters
- `.*` Match the whole string if assertions are true

##### Python Example

```py
import re

s1 = "My name is Jack Brown"
s2 = "I am Jack Brown"

def doesMatch(string):
    return bool(re.search(r"(?=^(?:(?!name).)*Jack.*$).*", string))

print(doesMatch(s1))  # False
print(doesMatch(s2))  # True
```

Also, see the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lga5WG/1)

Comment: thanks for reply, this regex will accept the other variations of Jack too, ex: `My name  is Jacky Chan`, but I need to match specific words, so I think handle it by boundaring word `Jack`, regex: `(?=^(?:(?!name).)*\bJack\b.*$).*`

Comment: Sure it is also a solution. My answer is about negating the `name` with `(?:(?!name).)*`

Comment: One more question, can we check if word `name` appears any where? After Jack or before Jack, does not matter, if word `name` is in string, it must return False, can you help for it?

Comment: Then you can use [`(?=^(?:(?!name).)*$).*`](https://regex101.com/r/V87x7B/1) to negate the `name` in the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disallow full word `name` *before* matching full word `Jack` then this regex will be much more efficient (take note of **number of steps** on regex101 site):

```bash
^(?:Jack\b|(?=\w+(?: +(?!name\b)\w+)* +Jack\b)).*
```

This regex uses alternation to either:

- Match `Jack` at the start *OR*
- Match `Jack` before matching 1+ words if that word is not full word `name`.

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/58bvox/1)

Now if you want to disallow full word `name` *anywhere* in the line i.e before or after then use:

```bash
^(?!.*\bname\b).*\bJack\b.*
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/58bvox/2)

Answer (score 1):

One can avoid regex and just use string index method.

```
s = 'My name is Jack Brown'
s.index('name') < s.index('Jack')
True
```

If one needs regex, the same indexing idea could be used as follows:

```
def check_string(s,name='nam', Jack='Jac'):
    try: 
        return re.search(rf'\b{name}.*?\b', s).start() < re.search(rf'\b{Jack}.*?\b', s).start()
    except Exception as e:
        return False

s = 'My is Jack Brown'
check_string(s)
False
s = 'My name is Jack Brown'
check_string(s)
True
```

Comment: Good idea but this way it's not possible to take word boundaries into account.

Comment: @bobblebubble. You are correct. I have added lines with the re.search which does also allow to compare indexes.  Now one can use the word boundaries with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is no `name` before `Jack` how about

```
^\W*(?:(?!name\b)\w+\W+)*?Jack.*
```

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dkOs8T/1)

This pattern checks if none of the words before jack is `name` by use of a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
`\w` matches a [word character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998550/5527985) and upper `\W` the negation of it (*non word characters*).