# Powershell allow only alphanumeric and specific special characters

Tags: powershell

I want to allow the dash -, _, . in the string

```
    $string = "atest-d56hdaff"
    
    If ($string -match "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]*$"){ 
        echo "OK"
        }
    else{
        echo "Not Ok"
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not need to double-escape the backslashes in .Net/PowerShell.  `^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*$` https://regex101.com/r/LSwznn/1

Comment: Besides, PowerShell is case-insensitive by nature, meaning this `a-zA-Z` unnecessary as well, and the is a general regex substitute for a [word character (`\w`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998519/1701026) which simplifies it to just: `^[\w\-\.]*$` and as an aside, I wonder if you actually want to allow an empty string, if not, you probably want use a plus (`+`) sign rather than an asterisk `*` sign.