# Regex Alphanumeric check

Tags: c#, regex

Tried to replace this code into Regex format

```
  public static bool isAlphaNumeric(string s)
    {
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (!(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') &&
                    !(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') &&
                    !(c >= '0' && c <= '9') && c != '(' && c != ')' && c != '-' && c != '\\' && c != '/' && c != '&' && c != ' ')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

With

```
        public static Boolean isAlphaNumeric(string strToCheck)
    {
        Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[a-z-A-Z0-9_\s&()'\\/-]{1,30}$");
        return rg.IsMatch(strToCheck);
    }
```

But the regex is NOT working ... need to allow only numbers, letters and the following characters ( ) - & \ /

Comment: What is not working exactly? I tried that Regex over at http://regexstorm.net/tester and it was matching for me.

Comment: The original  boolean check excluded these characters (in single quote): '()-/\& ' whereas you want to allow for them, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing an `\` and there's an extra `-` (I don't know if it makes a difference though).

Try this: `Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[\w\s&()'\\\/-]{1,30}$");`

Comment: `a-zA-Z0-9_` is equal to `\w`.

Comment: @Jan ...[not in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998519) though.

Comment: That is, unless [ECMAScript-compliant behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ecmascript-matching-behavior) is specified.